# Python IndexError: only integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm new to sklearn and having trouble formatting the data to predict and evaluate a confusion matrix.  I'm using this [Random Forest tutorial](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html).

Here is my code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('output.txt', sep='\t')
df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75
train, test = df[df['is_train']==True], df[df['is_train']==False]
features = df.columns[1:5]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
y, _ = pd.factorize(train['event_count'])
clf.fit(train[features], y)
```

This line for my predictions gives the error:

```
preds = df['event_count'][clf.predict(test[features])]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like it is this `df[:6]`. That's returning you every row up until 6, not the columns.

Comment: i updated to just select the one target column (not sure if that is correct), and I still get the same error

Comment: I believe this should work. Change `clf.fit(train[features], y)` to `model = clf.fit(train[features], y)`. Then do `preds = model.predict(test[features])`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: my issue was my 'test' variable did not get exectuted the first time around.  so now that works.